# Creating flexible EditText field based on textUri input type

Tags: android

I ran through Android network programming tutorial and stumbled upon something that annoys me:

> EditText field won't recognize URL without 'http://' prefix.
>   [image]

How to make EditText more flexible like Google Chrome's URL box such that it is able to accept input such as google.com, www.google.com without having to insert the http prefix?

Comment: you can put the http://  in the edit_text box before you write anything there. or you use a stringbuilder afterwards and put the http:// on front before you actually try to open the url

Comment: oh yes. such a foolish question. why didnt I think of that. thank you @bofredo